# How to convert string into ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am getting data from MongoDB and binding to a WPF datagrid.

My code selects multiple rows, retrieves IDs and updates the selected records:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create(this.connectionString);
var db = server.GetDatabase(DATABASE);
var viewTrue = db.GetCollection(RISKALERT_TBL);
var count = viewTrue.Count();
foreach (RiskSettings row in grdRiskAlerts.SelectedItems)
{
    viewTrue.Update(Query.EQ("ID",row.ID), Update.Set("View", "False"));
    LoadandBindData();
}
```

But it does not update the record.

I thought maybe row.id is returning string and ID datatype is objectId.

This query is working for other datatype except the above case.

Answer (score 25):

To convert a string to an `ObjectId`, use the [ObjectId.Parse(string)](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3.1/html/3321e7aa-fe9b-4940-be93-019ff33fed5d.htm) method.

Also try to match on `"_id"` rather than `"ID"`.

So something like:

```
viewTrue.Update(Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(row.ID)), Update.Set("View", "False"));
```

Comment: This only seems to work if the string is already an ObjectId. It doesn't seem to work for arbitrary strings.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin yes, it's like `int.Parse`. If the string can't be converted to an `ObjectId`, of course we can't expect it to work.

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same issue when setting up a public property for the ObjectID.

My property converted the ObjectID to a string, and back to an ObjectID using the following code snippet.

The ObjectID wasn't coming up as an option so I had to use the complete namespace, to access the `.Parse()` like this `MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.Parse`

```
    public string Id
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(_id); }
        set { _id = MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId.Parse(value); }
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I found was to use: `new ObjectId(yourString)` ...This will give you a MongoDB ObjectId from a string and should work with any of your queries.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to require the ObjectId function from your mongo.

```
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
ObjectId(row.ID)
```

So you can change your line of code to:

```
viewTrue.Update(Query.EQ("ID",ObjectId(row.ID)), Update.Set("View", "False"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is:

```
myString := "5f4f321d7125461260ad9d74"

objectId, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(myString)

if err != nil {
    panic("Invalid id")
}
```

Comment: This is the proper of doing it now. Thank you for the update

Answer (score 0):

if you use mgo, you can try this one

```
id := "603f4d6415177136d0583d4d"
_id := bson.ObjectIdHex(id)
```