# How to convert string to object in MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp, servlets, pojo

I have to get the existing id to update user information (e.g. email/name/password). I using POJOs to map the object id. I can see a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503673/how-to-convert-string-into-objectid), but in .Net

How can I do that to pass it to the constructor? (Sorry, I'm very new to MongoDB)

```
ObjectId _id = request.getParameter("id"); // "erro with Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to ObjectId"


User user = new User(_id, email, fullName, password);
```

Comment: Your question is lacking quite a lot of content. First of all what is the `ObjectId`. Aside from that. Pleas share more of your code.

Comment: @akortex91 sorry, I have another post about update user inform that I think the POJO class might causing this problem. Really sorry for the lack of context.

Answer (score 1):

can you show the POJO(class) it might be caused by the type you have user in your model for the id...I'm not able to tell you what is the problem but have a look at this link it might help you https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3677

Comment: I have another related post to this and have more code in it. The POJO I am using is following the quick start tutorial only.

Comment: so try to use simple type and see what it will do:

Comment: It can't get the the _id that saying something wrong with the autocodec...

Comment: Btw, is that possible to get the _id without POJO to map the model?

Comment: so try to use simple type and see what it will do: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709825/9936992] so instead of using ojectId read the policy and use simple types and see if it works

Comment: I don't now much about the internal architecture of pojo but you better not try to override ORMs

Comment: Thanks, if so, the POJO mapping is unnecessary to use in MongoDB with Java since I'm not using spring data

Comment: I go to the MongoDB community for support and solved my issue, thanks.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: I need to convert String to ObjectId.